# UART program on RPI 3 is not waiting for response

Tags: pi-3, c, uart

```
    #include <stdio.h>      // perror
    #include <sys/mman.h>   // mmap
    #include <sys/types.h>  // fd open
    #include <sys/stat.h>   // fd open
    #include <fcntl.h>      // fd open
    #include <unistd.h>     // fd close

    #define BCM2708_PERI_BASE        0x3F000000
    #define GPIO_BASE               (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x200000)   // GPIO controller
    #define UART0_BASE      (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x201000)

    #define BLOCK_SIZE              (4 * 1024)


    #define GPPUD           *(gpio.addr + 0x94)
    #define GPPUDCLK0       *(gpio.addr + 0x98)
    #define UART0_DR        *(uart.addr + 0x00)
    #define UART0_RSRECR    *(uart.addr + 0x04)
    #define UART0_FR        *(uart.addr + 0x18)
    #define UART0_ILPR      *(uart.addr + 0x20)
    #define UART0_IBRD      *(uart.addr + 0x24)
    #define UART0_FBRD      *(uart.addr + 0x28)
    #define UART0_LCRH      *(uart.addr + 0x2C)
    #define UART0_CR        *(uart.addr + 0x30)
    #define UART0_IFLS      *(uart.addr + 0x34)
    #define UART0_IMSC      *(uart.addr + 0x38)
    #define UART0_RIS       *(uart.addr + 0x3C)
    #define UART0_MIS       *(uart.addr + 0x40)
    #define UART0_ICR       *(uart.addr + 0x44)
    #define UART0_DMACR     *(uart.addr + 0x48)
    #define UART0_ITCR      *(uart.addr + 0x80)
    #define UART0_ITIP      *(uart.addr + 0x84)
    #define UART0_ITOP      *(uart.addr + 0x88)
    #define UART0_TDR       *(uart.addr + 0x8C)

    struct bcm2835_peripheral {
        unsigned long addr_p;
        int mem_fd;
        void *map;
        volatile unsigned int *addr;
    };

    struct bcm2835_peripheral gpio = { GPIO_BASE };
    struct bcm2835_peripheral uart = { UART0_BASE };

    // Exposes the physical address defined in the passed structure using mmap on /dev/mem
    int map_peripheral(struct bcm2835_peripheral *p)
    {
        // Open /dev/mem
        if ((p->mem_fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC) ) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open /dev/mem, try checking permissions.");
            return -1;
        }

        p->map = mmap(
                    NULL,
                    BLOCK_SIZE,
                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_SHARED,
                    p->mem_fd,      // File descriptor to physical memory virtual file '/dev/mem'
                    p->addr_p       // Address in physical map that we want this memory block to expose
                    );

        if (p->map == MAP_FAILED) {
            perror("mmap");
            return -1;
        }

        p->addr = (volatile unsigned int *)p->map;

        return 0;
    }

    void unmap_peripheral(struct bcm2835_peripheral *p)
    {

        munmap(p->map, BLOCK_SIZE);
        close(p->mem_fd);
    }

    static inline void delay(int32_t count)
    {
        asm volatile("__delay_%=: subs %[count], %[count], #1; bne __delay_%=\n"
                     : "=r"(count)
                     : [count] "0"(count)
                     : "cc");
    }


    void uart_init() {
        // Disable UART0.
        UART0_CR = 0x00000000;

        // Disable pull up/down for all GPIO pins & delay for 150 cycles.
        GPPUD = 0x00000000;
        delay(150);

        // Disable pull up/down for pin 14,15 & delay for 150 cycles.
        GPPUDCLK0 = (1 << 14) | (1 << 15);
        delay(150);

        // Write 0 to GPPUDCLK0 to make it take effect.
        GPPUDCLK0 =  0x00000000;

        // Clear pending interrupts.
        UART0_ICR =  0x7FF;

        // Set integer & fractional part of baud rate.
        // Divider = UART_CLOCK/(16 * Baud)
        // Fraction part register = (Fractional part * 64) + 0.5
        // UART_CLOCK = 3000000; Baud = 115200.

        // Divider = 3000000 / (16 * 115200) = 1.627 = ~1.
        UART0_IBRD = 1;

        // Fractional part register = (.627 * 64) + 0.5 = 40.6 = ~40.
        UART0_FBRD = 40;

        // Enable FIFO & 8 bit data transmissio (1 stop bit, no parity).
        UART0_LCRH = (1 << 4) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 6);

        // Mask all interrupts.
        UART0_IMSC = (1 << 1) | (1 << 4) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 6) |
                                   (1 << 7) | (1 << 8) | (1 << 9) | (1 << 10);

        // Enable UART0, receive & transfer part of UART.
        UART0_CR = (1 << 0) | (1 << 8) | (1 << 9);
    }


    void uart_putc(unsigned char c)
    {

        // Wait for UART to become ready to transmit.
        while (UART0_FR & (1 << 5))
        {}
        UART0_DR = c;
    }

    unsigned char uart_getc()
    {
        // Wait for UART to have received something.
        while (UART0_FR & (1 << 4))
        {}
        return UART0_DR;
    }

    void uart_puts(const char *str)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
            uart_putc((unsigned char)str[i]);
    }

    int main()
    {
        if(map_peripheral(&gpio) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to map the physical GPIO registers into the virtual memory space.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if(map_peripheral(&uart) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to map the physical UART0 registers into the virtual memory space.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        uart_init();

        uart_puts("Hello World \r\n");

        while(1){
            delay(150);
            printf("%c" , uart_getc()); //Not waiting on uart_getc
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This code works when I transmit data from RPI but it doesn't wait for response from other side. I expected it to block on uart_getc() until it receives response, instead it shows some garbage as response.

UART base addresses and baud rate calculations are referred from osdev wiki [link](http://wiki.osdev.org/Raspberry_Pi_Bare_Bones)

When I checked values at UART_0 registers all of them have value=0, even though I updated values in uart_init method.

Comment: Anybody who can help me here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register addresses were calculated incorrectly. According to pointer arithmetic in C if unsigned int * is incremented once it will point to 4 location further to its current address.

```
#define GPPUD           *(gpio.addr + 0x94/4)
#define GPPUDCLK0       *(gpio.addr + 0x98/4)
#define UART0_DR        *(uart.addr + 0x00/4)
#define UART0_RSRECR    *(uart.addr + 0x04/4)
#define UART0_FR        *(uart.addr + 0x18/4)
#define UART0_ILPR      *(uart.addr + 0x20/4)
#define UART0_IBRD      *(uart.addr + 0x24/4)
#define UART0_FBRD      *(uart.addr + 0x28/4)
#define UART0_LCRH      *(uart.addr + 0x2C/4)
#define UART0_CR        *(uart.addr + 0x30/4)
#define UART0_IFLS      *(uart.addr + 0x34/4)
#define UART0_IMSC      *(uart.addr + 0x38/4)
#define UART0_RIS       *(uart.addr + 0x3C/4)
#define UART0_MIS       *(uart.addr + 0x40/4)
#define UART0_ICR       *(uart.addr + 0x44/4)
#define UART0_DMACR     *(uart.addr + 0x48/4)
#define UART0_ITCR      *(uart.addr + 0x80/4)
#define UART0_ITIP      *(uart.addr + 0x84/4)
#define UART0_ITOP      *(uart.addr + 0x88/4)
#define UART0_TDR       *(uart.addr + 0x8C/4)
```

Also check which uart module you are using mini uart or pl11 in raspberry pi 3